# PHP Get to URL redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, parameters

Hey i have the following issues / thinking problem

```
<?php
$fname=$_GET['buyer_first_name'];
$lname=$_GET['buyer_last_name'];
$email=$_GET['buyer_email'];
$orderid=$_GET['order_id']

?>
```

This parameters will coming in by GET and after they get in / i would love an automatic redirect to the following URL with the above parameters in it

www.mydomain.com/query.php?k=test&action=add&r=$orderid&n=$email

How can i do that? My main problem is how i can set the different parameters in the url..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can first check the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` if it is a 'GET' and check if all your expected parameters are set.
Then you can use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to build your url and use [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to go to your url.

```
if (
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' &&
    isset($_GET['buyer_first_name']) &&
    isset($_GET['buyer_last_name']) &&
    isset($_GET['buyer_email']) &&
    $_GET['order_id']
) {
    $params = array(
        'k' => 'test',
        'action' => 'add',
        'r' => $_GET['order_id'],
        'n' => $_GET['buyer_email']
    );

    $url = 'www.mydomain.com/query.php?' .  http_build_query($params);
    header("location:" . $url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header("location: www.mydomain.com/query.php?k=test&action=add&r=$orderid&n=$email");
```

If you use header('location... make sure nothing is visible on the page, otherwise you'll get a "headers already sent, output started...." error.

Answer (score 0):

This should pretty much do what you are trying to accomplish

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && isset( $_GET['buyer_first_name'],$_GET['buyer_last_name'],$_GET['buyer_email'],$_GET['order_id'] ) ){

        header( "location: www.mydomain.com/query.php?k=test&action=add&r={$_GET['order_id']}&n={$_GET['buyer_email']}" );

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

http_build_query is a cool function

```
$parameters = array(
  'k'      => 'test',
  'action' => 'add',
  'r'      => $orderid,
  'n'      => $email,
);

$target = 'www.mydomain.com/query.php';
$url = $target.'?'.http_build_query($parameters);
header("location: $url");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below :

```
<?php
$fname='';$lname='';$email='';$orderid='';
if(isset($_GET['buyer_first_name']))
    $fname=stripslashes($_GET['buyer_first_name']);
if(isset($_GET['buyer_last_name']))
    $lname=stripslashes($_GET['buyer_last_name']);
if(isset($_GET['buyer_email']))
    $email=stripslashes($_GET['buyer_email']);
if(isset($_GET['order_id']))
    $orderid=stripslashes($_GET['order_id']);
$fullurl = "www.mydomain.com/query.php?k=test&action=add&r=".$orderid."&n=".$email;
header("location:".$fullurl);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$querystring = "www.websitedomain.com/redirect.php?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
header('location:'.$querystring);
```